# Count with Alloy under a specific condition

Tags: alloy

I need to count how many ticket have the same time and, then, to compare this number with the maximum permitted seats at a specific hour, but I'am experiencing some problems in this task. How I can define this fact constraint in Alloy?
This is the organization of Ticket and TicketQueue,which contains the maximum number of seats.

```
sig Ticket{   

    owner:one User,
    date: one Date,
    time: one Time,
    status : one Status,
}

sig TicketQueue {
   
    simultaneous_seats: one Int,
    ticket: some Ticket,
    manager: one SM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work. (It helps, btw, to provide a compilable code example.)

```
sig Time {}
sig Ticket { time : Time }
```

> to count how many ticket have the same time
> to compare this number with the maximum permitted seats at a specific hour

```
run {
   all t : Time | # time.t < 3
} for 8
```

Comment: I'd add that you have to make sure to forbid  integer overflow in the options, else you might get funny results